# Debian 11 Bullseye encrypted LVM times out on first boot attempt

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, lvm, initramfs-tools

I attempted to install Debian Bullseye with an encrypted LVM and have run into this problem for the first time trying to boot after installation.

```
Volume group "system" not found
Cannot process volume group system
Volume group "system" not found
Cannot process volume group system
Volume group "system" not found
Cannot process volume group system
...
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot arge (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules cat /proc/modules; ls dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/system does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Debian 1:1.30.1-4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

I know the initial part where it claims it can't find the volume group is an aesthetic issue that has always existed in Debian, based on my previous experience with encrypted LVMs. However, I have never had it time out like this.

I have noticed `/etc/fstab` is empty. I'm not sure why this is the case, but I assume this might be part of the issue(?)

In terms of how I installed, I didn't do anything out of the ordinary. I have tried both manual encrypted LVM configuration, and guided. Both have the same issue. I have also used this configuration on Debian systems in the past with no issues. Not sure what I am doing wrong, or if/how I can fix it. Also, if I screwed up the installation somehow, I don't mind reinstalling since this is a brand new installation.

Output of `dpkg -l | grep -i lvm`:

```
ii libllvm2cmd2.03:amd64 1:8.0.1-3+b1
ii liblvm2cmd2.03:amd64 2.03.02-3
ii lvm2 2.03.02-3
```

Output of `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>    <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/system-root /                   ext4   errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=6adc2d5d-f5fe-4bd1-a1a3-38089968c1a2 /boot      ext2    defaults      0       2
/dev/mapper/system-home /home               ext4   defaults    0        2
/dev/mapper/system-tmp /tmp                ext4   defaults    0        2
/dev/mapper/system-var /var                ext4   defaults    0        2
/dev/mapper/system-swap none                  swap   sw          0         0
```

Output of `/etc/crypttab`:

```
nvme0n1p5_crypt UUID=5e7ea67f-3c1a-4192-b4fb-2b51ab21ea55 /etc/luks-keys/nvme0n1p5_crypt luks,discard
```

Abridged output of `dpkg -l | grep -i crypt`:

```
cryptsetup                2:2.2.1-1
cryptsetup-bin            2:2.2.1-1
cryptsetup-initramfs      2:2.2.1-1
cryptsetup-run            2:2.2.1-1
gcr                       3.33.4-2
gnupg-agent               2.2.17-3
gpg-agent                 2.2.17-3
libcprov-java             1.61-1
libblockdev-crypto2       2.22-1
libcryptsetup12           2:2.2.1-1
libgcr-base-3-1           3.33.4-2
libgcr-ui-3-1             3.33.4-2
libcrypt20                1.8.5-2
libhogweed4               3.4.1-1+b1
libk5crypto3              1.17-6
libmbedcrypto3            2.16.2-1
libmbedtls12              2.16.2-1
libmbedx509-0             2.16.2-1
libmhash2                 0.9.9.9-7.1
libnettle6                3.4.1-1+b1
libsodium23               1.0.18-1
libssh-gcrypt-4           0.9.0-1
libvolume-key1            0.3.12-2+b1
node-bcrypt-pbkdf         1.0.1-1
node-tweetnacl            1.0.1+dfsg-2
openssl                   1.1.1c-1
python-asn1crypto         0.24.0-1
python-crypto             2.6.1-10
python-cryptography       2.6.1-3
python3-asn1crypto        0.24.0-1
python3-crypto            2.6.1-10
python3-cryptography      2.6.2-3
python3-gpg               1.13.1-1
```

Comment: Could you add the content of your `/etc/crypttab`, as well as the output of the following command: `dpkg -l | grep -i lvm` to your question.

Comment: I don't have access to those commands, as I can't even boot. It gets stuck at `initramfs`. I also can't mount my system drive since my fstab is empty.

Comment: You cannot repair the system from within `initramfs`'s shell. You have to boot from a Debian live CD or USB drive. This will enable you to open the encrypted volume (`cryptsetup open`), mount your drives / partitions / logical volumes etc. (`mount`), chroot into the damaged system (`chroot`), investigate the situation (my 1st comment) and finally fix the errors (most probably you have to regenerate your `initramfs`). This might sound quiet complicated, if you have never done it before and you will probably get stuck at some point, but I promise you will learn a lot about how your system works.

Comment: I for sure will give that a shot when I am home. What confuses me is that a guided setup with default configuration doesn't work. I've tried on my hardware + a virtualbox VM. Why would debian allow their installer to do this? I've installed encrypted LVMs with it before, never had this issue. But I've tried doing this on several releases within the past few months, and they've all had this issue.

Comment: We will find out it this is an installer bug, or not. There is a good answer over at askubuntu, describing the procedure: https://askubuntu.com/a/653460 Please report back when you were able to `chroot` into the damaged installation. If you do this within a VM, do not turn it off but save its state so that you do not have to do this multiple times.

Comment: I finally got around to giving this a go. 

    # dpkg -l | grep -i lvm
    ii  libllvm2cmd2.03:amd64    1:8.0.1-3+b1
    ii  liblvm2cmd2.03:amd64     2.03.02-3
    ii  lvm2                                   2.03.02-3

Comment: Output of commands is hard to read at the comments section. So please do not add information as comments, but instead edit / extend your question. Please also add content of the `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab` files, as well as the output of `$ dpkg -l | grep -i crypt`. If they are empty you have to populate them, as described here https://askubuntu.com/questions/435965/accidentally-deleted-etc-fstab-file and here https://askubuntu.com/questions/5861/etc-crypttab-not-working Afterwards you probably have to regenerate `initramfs` with `update-initramfs -k all -u`.

Comment: So one thing I did was to install debian stable, and then upgrade to testing. This worked for a little while and through multiple reboots, but then I installed a bunch of packages that I had on my old machine, which still works fine, and after a reboot the same problem happened again. I guess good (?) news is that the fstab is populated and looks normal. I will add the output to the original post along with the other requested information.

Comment: Hey, @dirdi, wondering if you have any more input on this. I'm happy to do the work, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I also updated my packages from the live USB and got the warning `WARNING: target 'system' not found in /etc/crypttab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed the key file (`/etc/luks-keys/nvme0n1p5_crypt`) to unlock your encrypted volume inside the encrypted volume (Like a locked car with the keys laying on the dashboard). Change your `/etc/crypttab` to:

```
nvme0n1p5_crypt UUID=5e7ea67f-3c1a-4192-b4fb-2b51ab21ea55 none luks,discard
```

Afterwards, regenerate *initramfs* with `update-initramfs -k all -u`.

At the next boot you should be asked to provide your passphrase to unlock the encrypted device. LVM should then be able to find and map the `system` volume group and boot should proceed.

Comment: Amazing, you're my hero. I suppose I'd have to make a new partition to put the keyfile somewhere outside the encrypted lvm, hm?

Comment: @AdumbCopper No, that would be a bad idea. It would be like locking your car but leaving the keys laying on its roof. Everybody who drops by could steal the keys. Therefore this would make encryption obsolete. Instead you should type in your passphrase at every boot.